# What parameters does BeautfilSoup() accept to create BeautifulSoup object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urlopen

How am I supposed to know BeautifulSoup() accepts httpResponse object, which urlopen() returns when BeautifulSoup documentation does not mention that it does?

Can someone elaborate the range of parameter types that BeautifulSoup() accepts?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: `help(BeautifulSoup)` and other `bs4` documentation. When in doubt, ask for `help()`.