# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'feature'

Tags: python

[Help me to resolve this webscraping code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVDSY.png)

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

header = {"User-Agent":"Google Chrome"}
req = Request("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/india/", headers = header)
html = urlopen(req)
html.status
obj = bs(html, feature='lxml')
new_cases = obj.find("li", {"class":"news_li"}).strong.text.split()[0]
death = list(obj.find("li", {"class":"news_li"}).strong.next_siblings)[1].text.split()[0]
```

struck in this for hours and hours

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. There is no keyword argument named feature in bs(). Have you looked at the library documentation ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740164/what-parameters-does-beautfilsoup-accept-to-create-beautifulsoup-object

Comment: Replace the line to obj = bs(html, 'lxml')

Answer (score 0):

The keyword argument is `features` not `feature`. [(Source)](https://github.com/getanewsletter/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py)

Replace this line in your code:

```
obj = bs(html, feature='lxml')
```

With this one:

```
obj = bs(html, features='lxml')
```